# Unable to use variable declared in a function inside another function

Tags: php, mysql

Didn't know how to ask this question.

I was working on setting up class to handle my Database interaction and have a weird interaction of passing variables. I must be missing something.

I have a class `DataBaseAPI` I have a function `QueryDB($value)` that will be called by other functions. But it has an issue with my declaring that `$value` inside another function. Example:

Works

```
include_once('DataBaseAPI.php');
$DB = new DataBaseAPI();

$test = $DB->QueryDB('id');
echo $test;
```

Doesn't Work

```
include_once('DataBaseAPI.php');
$DB = new DataBaseAPI();

$test = $DB->getId();
echo $test;
```

Start of the class in `DataBaseAPI.php`

```
class DataBaseAPI {


  public function getId(){
    //the same function defined the same way but needing to use $this
    $this->QueryDB('id');//seems like a waste here but is for ease of use later on
  }


  public function QueryDB($value){
    echo $value; //echo's id
    global $conn; 
    $token = '7ci4f8ykfik3ndzufksy1dp16x3na4'; //Test Token not a real token
    $doesExists = "SELECT $value FROM user_info WHERE token='$token'";
    $existsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $doesExists);
    $check = $existsResult->fetch_assoc();
    return $check[$value];
  }
}
```

I even checked with an echo the `$value` in the `QueryDB($value)` echo's `id` the same way as when I call the function directly.

I just don't understand why the first method works yet the second method doesn't, yet I'm still calling it the same way. Just inside another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the result of `getId()` in order to store in your `$test`. Do

```
 public function getId(){
    return $this->QueryDB('id');//seems like a waste here but is for ease of use later on
  }
```

instead of

```
 public function getId(){
    $this->QueryDB('id');//seems like a waste here but is for ease of use later on
  }
```

Comment: oh. haha make since now that someone said it. Thanks for the quick response!